# Is it possible to pass LIVE VIEW name as a parameter in Clickhouse query?

Tags: clickhouse

For example, like

```
CREATE LIVE VIEW %(live_view_name)s WITH REFRESH
```

It works only with other parameters (WHERE condition) but not with view name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like you use python for make HTTP query?

I think it's not possible because parameter value will escape as string literal, not as field name

Look to
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/interfaces/http#cli-queries-with-parameters
and

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/interfaces/cli#cli-queries-with-parameters

and try to use `CREATE LIVE VIEW {live_view_name:Identifier} WITH REFRESH`